# wordpress ftp using google cloud platform

Tags: wordpress, ftp, google-cloud-platform

I am doing some testing to determine the feasibility of moving my small web hosting business over to Google Cloud Platform. All of my client websites are Wordpress sites built by me and i also fully manage them.

I have setup a free 60 day trial and am about to install my first project...which will be a prebuilt CMS  (Wordpress) found in the software packages list in Google Developers Console.

There are at least 2 things i am wanting to test...
1. using wordpress multisite (as i intend to move all of my existing clients websites into Wordpress MU
2. Speed of websites on this network (one concern is latency as the datacenter location not being in my country)

So in order to test the above, i would like to setup some clones of existing client websites on the Google Cloud Project i create.

**Question...**

How do i get file and directory access to the Wordpress CMS on Google Cloud so i can upload Websites produced on my local system or another server?

(i need to copy up media files e.g. images, content, and themes)

Or is my only means of file directory access via Wordpress plugins with this solution?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which tool you choose to use.

If you use [Wordpress for AppEngine](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/), you'll have to use a combination of deployment techniques and plugins to get data onto your instance.

If you use [Wordpress Multisite](https://cloud.google.com/launcher/solution/bitnami-launchpad/wordpress-multisite?hl=en) then you would interact with it just like any other install of Wordpress.

Comment: Hi terry. Thanks for replying. I ended up choosing the wordpress compute deployment solution for starters. You were correct, using the right plugins can resolve this issue, but not so easy using app engine so i went with a compute vm. Am having problems getting sftp to work from my windows 10 computer with filezilla but that is another discussion. I can access vm using the ssh link in console which is a start.

Answer (score 1):

1) Create a key pairing (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#standardssh)

2) Connect via SFTP (CyberDuck, FileZilla)

3) Upload files into your /home/*yourusername* directory

4) Connect to the server via shell, you can do this from your Google Dashboard (Google Shell)

5) Change your user to Root by typing `sudo /bin/bash`

6) Now you can move files `sudo mv file/you/want/to/move.html /var/www/html/`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use [SFTP](https://www.siteyaar.com/google-cloud-ftp-and-sftp-setup/), but if you want to connect with FTP see [this blog](https://www.siteyaar.com/setup-ftp-server-on-google-cloud/) to solve your problems.

If your VM is based on Linux then you have to use an application like `vsftpd` to set up an FTP server.

Here are the steps:

1. Deploy a Virtual Instance on Google Cloud
2. Open SSH terminal
3. Installing VSFTPD
4. Create a User
5. Configure vsftpd.conf file
6. Preparing an FTP Directory
7. FTP/S or FTP over SSL setup (optional)
8. Opening Ports in Google Cloud Firewall
9. Test and Connect